How to put an api on Bigquery requests?
My data was previously on aws and I used api gateway linked to a lambda. The lambda function written in python contains several requests and these requests call an Athena table and returns results. I display these results in my front end. Data are cached thanks to api gateway.
Now I migrated my data to Bigquery and i re-created all the requests.
How I can have the same flow ? How can I access from my front end the results of my requests ? Also how can I protect this api ?
The solution i have in mind is to keep my lambda in Aws and my api gateway and instead of calling my Athena in AWS, I call bigquery from Aws then return the result to the front.
But I don't know if it is the good thing to do.
Thanks.

Typically not ideal wrt data transfer charges to go cross-cloud imo. Note that Google Cloud offers both API Gateway and Cloud Functions.

What's your current authentication on Lambda?

@guillaumeblaquiere today on lambda, i use cognito token to have access to my api gateway. This way, my api is secured.

@jarmod thank you. So the solution suggested is to use a cloud functions and put an api gateway in front. Thank you.

Do you want to continue to use Cognito? Or do you plan to migrate the cognito entries too? (with Google email for example)

Cognito is still the entrypoint for our system because our servers are on AWS. Just for the data on gcp, i want to fully use gcp systems.

I recommend migrating your application directly to Google Cloud Platform (GCP). You can use either Cloud Functions or Cloud Run to deploy your APIs in a serverless environment. Additionally, the GCP API Gateway can be leveraged to secure your applications.
To protect your APIs, it's crucial to limit the ingress access and enforce user authentication for consuming the APIs

Thank you. Ok for the cloud function. But how could i secure it ?

Google Cloud Function invocation is protected by IAM permissions.  The caller has to be authorized to invoke the Cloud Function.  I am assuming that you could create a Cloud Function that executes as a Service Account that is authorized to query the table.  Now you would protect the execution of the Cloud Function such that only authorized users of IT can execute the function and retrieve the data.
